JasperReports lineChart line order
I have a multiAxisChart which contains lineChart and barChart. lineChart contains two series as below and I want SeriesLast to be drawn last overwriting SeriesFirst if some values are same for both series. Now SeriesFirst is drawn last overwriting SeriesLast. I tried changing order of categorySeries elements but didn't work.
                                <dataset>
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="persons" uuid="db4c60de-ae28-495a-8940-f6bd56299e03">                                       
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{personDataSet}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                </dataset>
                                <categorySeries>
                                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SeriesLast"]]></seriesExpression>
                                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{month}]]></categoryExpression>
                                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Personage}]]></valueExpression>
                                    <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{Personage}+""]]></labelExpression>
                                </categorySeries>
                                <categorySeries>
                                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SeriesFirst"]]></seriesExpression>
                                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{month}]]></categoryExpression>
                                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{monthPerson}]]></valueExpression>
                                    <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{monthPerson}+""]]></labelExpression>
                                </categorySeries>
                            </categoryDataset>
                            <linePlot isShowLines="true" isShowShapes="false">
                                <plot>
                                    <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#FFAB40"/>
                                    <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#4472C4"/>
                                    <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#A5A5A5"/>
                                </plot>

